# Stubbing SOAP requests in Scala

Tags: scala, soap, netty, scalaxb, betamax

I use [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/) to generate models and client part of the SOAP interface. For testing I use [Betamax](https://github.com/robfletcher/betamax), which can also be used in [Scala](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2013/07/18/betamax-in-scala.html). However, scalaxb uses Netty as a transport, which [ignores proxy settings](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1133) set up by Betamax. How would you cope with this situation?

scalaxb uses cake pattern, so the service is built from 3 parts like in the following [example](http://scalaxb.org/wsdl-support):

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val service = (new stockquote.StockQuoteSoap12Bindings with
  scalaxb.SoapClientsAsync with
  scalaxb.DispatchHttpClientsAsync {}).service
val fresponse = service.getQuote(Some("GOOG"))
val response = Await.result(fresponse, 5 seconds)
println(response)
```

And tests:

```
import co.freeside.betamax.{TapeMode, Recorder}
import co.freeside.betamax.proxy.jetty.ProxyServer
import dispatch._
import org.scalatest.{Tag, FunSuite}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

class StockquoteSpec extends FunSuite with Betamax {

  testWithBetamax("stockquote", Some(TapeMode.READ_WRITE))("stockquote") { 
    val fresponse = service.getQuote(Some("GOOG"))
    val response = Await.result(fresponse, 5 seconds)
    println(response)
  }
}

trait Betamax {

  protected def test(testName: String, testTags: Tag*)(testFun: => Unit)

  def testWithBetamax(tape: String, mode: Option[TapeMode] = None)(testName: String, testTags: Tag*)(testFun: => Unit) = {
    test(testName, testTags: _*) {
      val recorder = new Recorder
      val proxyServer = new ProxyServer(recorder)
      recorder.insertTape(tape)
      recorder.getTape.setMode(mode.getOrElse(recorder.getDefaultMode()))
      proxyServer.start()
      try {
        testFun
      } finally {
        recorder.ejectTape()
        proxyServer.stop()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Versions:

- net.databinder.dispatch 0.11.2
- co.freeside.betamax 1.1.2
- com.ning.async-http-client 1.8.10
- io.netty.netty 3.9.2.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to use proxy with Netty. Although Netty does not read system properties for proxy settings, the settings can be injected using `ProxyServerSelector`. It is created in `build` method of `AsyncHttpClientConfig`:

```
if (proxyServerSelector == null && useProxySelector) {
    proxyServerSelector = ProxyUtils.getJdkDefaultProxyServerSelector();
}

if (proxyServerSelector == null && useProxyProperties) {
    proxyServerSelector = ProxyUtils.createProxyServerSelector(System.getProperties());
}

if (proxyServerSelector == null) {
    proxyServerSelector = ProxyServerSelector.NO_PROXY_SELECTOR;
}
```

The only obstacle is that `scalaxb` uses default config with `useProxyProperties=false`. You can override it with custom `MyDispatchHttpClientsAsync` that you can use when creating the service:

```
val service = (new stockquote.StockQuoteSoap12Bindings with
  scalaxb.SoapClientsAsync with
  MyDispatchHttpClientsAsync {}).service
```

And the source code of `MyDispatchHttpClientsAsync` (the key point is calling `setUseProxyProperties(true)`):

```
import com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider
import com.ning.http.client.{AsyncHttpClientConfig, AsyncHttpClient}
import scalaxb.HttpClientsAsync

/**
 * @author miso
 */
trait MyDispatchHttpClientsAsync extends HttpClientsAsync {
  lazy val httpClient = new DispatchHttpClient {}

  trait DispatchHttpClient extends HttpClient {
    import dispatch._, Defaults._

    // Keep it lazy. See https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/pull/279
    lazy val http = new Http(new AsyncHttpClient(new NettyAsyncHttpProvider(new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setUseProxyProperties(true).build())))
//    lazy val http = Http.configure(_.setUseProxyProperties(true)) // Maybe later. See https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/issues/312

    def request(in: String, address: java.net.URI, headers: Map[String, String]): concurrent.Future[String] = {
      val req = url(address.toString).setBodyEncoding("UTF-8") <:< headers << in
      http(req > as.String)
    }
  }
}
```